# iOS: Custom top segmented control works as expected only when using debugger

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to create a custom top swipe menu that has a moving resizing orange bar that denotes which tab is selected. This is an extremely common design and I'm just doing this for practice as I am new to swift. You navigate by either swiping through the bottom collectionView or you can select a tab on the top menu. The top menu is also just a collectionView and is scrollable as well.

As you can see below (first gif), my problem is that when I try to go back to the first tab, whether by swiping the bottom or by selecting the top, the orange bar does not move to the left edge of the screen as expected. Everything else works fine. However, when I turn on the debugger and insert breakpoints (second gif), the orange bar behaves as expected again.

My guess is that this has something to do with the order in which the views are updated or something to do with the timing in which the scrolling animation ends. And it must be affecting the way I am calculating the position of the orange bar. Which is why when the debugger is on and the animation is slowed down, the orange bar behaves as expected. However, since I'm pretty inexperienced, I am not sure how to pinpoint the problem.

My implementation is overriding `scrollViewDidScroll` of the bottom content view, checking if the user has scrolled past more than half of the current page. If yes, then call `topMenu.collectionView.setContentOffset` to scroll the top menu to its proper position and also call `animateHorizontalBar(index: Int)` as shown below, which takes the index of the target page.

FYI: `array` just contains Strings for the title of each tab. I am using the size of the strings to calculate the size and position of the orange bar.

**EDIT:** Going to first index is fine when I disabled the feature when the horizontal bar will follow the selected tab when top menu is scrolled (second gif)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
func moveHorizontalBar(index: Int) {
    let horizontalBar = topMenu.horizontalBarView

    var sizeArray: [CGFloat] = []

    for item in array {
        sizeArray.append((ceil(40 + (item as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)]).width)))
    }

    let width = self.view.frame.width
    let ratio = (topMenu.collectionView.contentSize.width - width) / (collectionView.contentSize.width - width)
    let offset = CGFloat(index) * width * ratio

    if index == 0 {
        horizontalBar.frame.origin.x = 0.0
        horizontalBar.frame.size.width = sizeArray[index]
    } else {
        var x: CGFloat = 0.0
        for i in 0..<index {
            x += sizeArray[i]
        }
        topMenu.currentOffset = x
        horizontalBar.frame.origin.x = x - offset
        horizontalBar.frame.size.width = sizeArray[index]
    }
}

func animateHorizontalBar(index: Int, animated: Bool) {
    if animated {
        self.topMenu.isSelectingNewTab = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.moveHorizontalBar(index: index)
        })
    } else {
        moveHorizontalBar(index: index)
    }
}
```

[image: Unexpected behaviour when going to first tab][image: Works when horizontal bar following top menu feature is disabled]

Comment: No issues with implementation. the problem is, while tapping 0th index you are setting content offset and moving horizontal bar. but the layout was not updated meantime. so move horizontal bar once viewdidlayoutsubviews that might fix the issue

Comment: Also, what is 'isSelectingNewTab = true', where you set it to false?

Comment: @AndrewRomanov because when topMenu (also a collectionview) is being scrolled by a user, i need to also make sure that the horizontal bar moves at the same rate with it. However, when a selection happens (such as swiping the bottom content view or tapping on a tab), the top menu and horizontal bar may move at different rates. I check 'isSelectingNewTab' in 'scrollviewdidscroll' of the topMenu to see whether topMenu is scrolling because of a selection or because of the user scrolling it. If it is the user scrolling, then I move the horizontal bar at the same rate as 'topMenu.contentOffset'

Comment: @karthik I'll give your suggestion a try when I get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: @karthik I gave your suggestion a try which allowed going to the 0th index just fine but now when I swipe between pages, the bar will move too far ahead before bouncing back. On another note, when I remove the code that moves horizontal bar along with top menu when it is scrolled, the original problem is solved (going to 0th index). So now I'm thinking it might actually be that bit of code that's incorrect. But the new question now is how do I enable the feature where if you scroll through the top menu tabs, the horizontal bar will follow which ever tab was selected

Comment: please have a look at this. our own framework that can solve your problem. or read it you can get an idea from it. https://github.com/sathishvgs/CustomSegmentControl