# Syncing Two CollectionViews For Navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I’m trying to sync two collection views proportionally for navigation. One of the collection views is menu-like and is at the top, and the second is a larger one below. What I would like is for the top collection view to scroll a distance of the width of one cell (the cells are dynamically sized) when the user scrolls the bottom collection view  a distance of the main screen’s width. The closest thing I've seen to this effect would be [iOS: Custom top segmented control works as expected only when using debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357768/ios-custom-top-segmented-control-works-as-expected-only-when-using-debugger). What I would like to change is to have the left most cell in the top menu always selected. In addition, when the user scrolls the bottom collection view the width of the screen, a new cell should Replace the left-most cell in the upper menu and be selected. Any help in Swift would be especially appreciated, but ObjC answers are also welcome.

Comment: Please post a minimum, verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so someone can help you solve the issue.

Comment: I edited to include an example.